# stroke an svg but only 3 of the 4 sides?

Tags: css, svg

I want the right side of the triangle to not have a stroke. Similar to what you can do with `border-right: none` in css.

Is this possible?

```
<span class="ui-icon">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 30 30" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" class="arrow">
    <g>
      <path d="M-3.55271368e-15,30 L3.55271368e-15,0 L30,15 L-3.55271368e-15,30 Z"></path>
    </g>
  </svg>
</span>


  g path {
    fill: @white;
    stroke: @ui-tooltip-border-color;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is also the option, of course, of not drawing that side at all.

```css
path {
  fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  stroke: rgb(255, 170, 255);
  stroke-width: 0.5px;
}
svg {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
}
body {
  background: ivory;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 30 30" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" class="arrow">
  <g>
    <path d="M3.55271368e-15,0 L30,15 L-3.55271368e-15,30"></path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this, playing around with [stroke-dasharray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dasharray) and [stroke-dashoffset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dashoffset) :

```css
path {
  fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  stroke-dashoffset: -164;
  stroke: rgb(255, 170, 255);
  stroke-dasharray: 67;
  stroke-width: 0.5px;
}
svg {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
}
body {
  background: ivory;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 30 30" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" class="arrow">
  <g>
    <path d="M-3.55271368e-15,30 L3.55271368e-15,0 L30,15 L-3.55271368e-15,30 Z"></path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I know you wanted the right border to be un-stroked but, in your path there were only 3 sides on the 4 announced and two of them were on the right. So, to avoid an impossible choice, I took the left as an example.

Comment: Yeah. Sorry I forgot to add the rotate 180deg rule